# Prolog: Constraining the elements of a list to be within a range

Tags: prolog, range, constraint-programming, clpfd

Are there any ways to constrain the elements of a list to be within a range, something that would look more like `1-6`, instead of using `between(1, 6, X)`?

Comment: Are we talking about integers or floats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `clpfd` library, has an [**`ins/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ins/2) predicate, where you can specify - for a list of variables - the range of the elements.

Like:

```
all_between(Low, High, Vars) :-
    Vars ins Low..High.
```

When calling `all_between(1,6,[X1,X2,X3]).` we get:

```
X1 in 1..6,
X2 in 1..6,
X3 in 1..6.
```

In case we want to enumerate over the elements, we can use `label(L).` as well, to assign values:

```
all_between_enumerate(Low, High, Vars) :-
    Vars ins Low..High,
    label(Vars).
```

For `all_between_enumerate(1,2,[X1,X2,X3]).` this generates:

```
?- all_between_enumerate(1,2,[X1,X2,X3]).
X1 = X2, X2 = X3, X3 = 1 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = 1,
X3 = 2 ;
X1 = X3, X3 = 1,
X2 = 2 ;
X1 = 1,
X2 = X3, X3 = 2 ;
X1 = 2,
X2 = X3, X3 = 1 ;
X1 = X3, X3 = 2,
X2 = 1 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = 2,
X3 = 1 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = X3, X3 = 2.
```

In case you already added constraints to the variables, like `X1 #< X3`, these are taken into account as well:

```
?- X1 #< X3, all_between_enumerate(1,2,[X1,X2,X3]).
X1 = X2, X2 = 1,
X3 = 2 ;
X1 = 1,
X3 = X2, X2 = 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use **library CLPFD** :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

constraint_list([]).
constraint_list([H|T]):-H in 1..6 ,label([H]),constraint_list(T).
```

Examples:

```
?- constraint_list([X1,X2]).
X1 = X2, X2 = 2 ;
X1 = 2,
X2 = 3 ;
X1 = 2,
X2 = 4 ;
X1 = 2,
X2 = 5 ;
X1 = 3,
X2 = 2 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = 3 ;
X1 = 3,
X2 = 4 ;
X1 = 3,
X2 = 5 ;
X1 = 4,
X2 = 2 ;
X1 = 4,
X2 = 3 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = 4 ;
X1 = 4,
X2 = 5 ;
X1 = 5,
X2 = 2 ;
X1 = 5,
X2 = 3 ;
X1 = 5,
X2 = 4 ;
X1 = X2, X2 = 5.

?- L=[1,2,3] ,constraint_list(L).
false.

?- L=[2,2,3] ,constraint_list(L).
L = [2, 2, 3].

?- constraint_list(L).
L = [] ;
L = [2] ;
L = [2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] ;
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] .
    ... (and goes on)
```